# Scrollbar Appearance Control in Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, scrollbar

I have an application that has a ListView control with scrollbars, and it has the cool looking scrollbars in it automatically:

```
CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,L"SysListView32",L"MyList",
WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|LVS_NOSCROLL|LVS_REPORT|LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER|WS_VSCROLL|LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS| LVS_SINGLESEL,
0,0,500,290,ownerhWnd, (HMENU)0,hInst,NULL);
```

However, when I create a Scrollbar control manually for another part of the application, it has the older 3d-style look:

```
CreateWindow(TEXT("SCROLLBAR"), TEXT("MyScrollBar"),
WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBS_VERT,0,0, CW_USEDEFAULT,
100, ownerhWnd, (HMENU)10 , NULL, NULL);
```

How do I get it to have the new look? Is there another control I use, or a style that I can apply to the standard control? I looked into the Flat Scroll Bar, however it says that it is not supported from XP onwards?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an open door, but you have added a Windows XP/Vista/7 manifest to your application's resources?

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I have never used this before, thanks for the help!

Comment: what does "Maybe an open door" mean in this context?  I've never heard it.  I can guess from context of course but it'd be cool to know...

Comment: Ah, it seems to be a typical Dutch saying? It is short for "kicking in an open door" witch translates as "doing unnecessary work". In this case it is meant as a friendly form of "stating the obvious", a truism.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to create a manifest for your program that indicates it uses Common Controls version 6. Then you have to call `InitCommonControls` at program startup.

Details are found on this Microsoft page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx